# Incorrect argument being passed to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am building a simple website for my family to track the jigsaw puzzles they own. One feature is the ability to delete a puzzle they no longer own. I intend to pass the row ID to a separate file as an argument, but thought I should put a javascript confirmation popup in the middle. I seem to have everything running almost correctly, but the argument being passed is incorrect and I don't know why. It is passing the ID of the last row in the table, rather than the current row ID. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

#### PHP Code

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "<script>var puzzleID = " . $row['id'] . "</script>";
  echo "<td><a href='puzzleedit.php?=" . $row['id'] . "'>Edit</a> | <button onclick='confirmationBox()'>Delete</button></td>";
}
```

#### JS Code in a separate file

```
function confirmationBox() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this puzzle?")) {
        window.location = './puzzledelete.php?=' + puzzleID
    } else {
    }
}
```

The interesting thing is that using `$row['id']` in the edit link works as expected, it is grabbing the correct row ID from the database. The `$row['id']` in the script is grabbing the table's last row ID.

Comment: there is only one `var puzzleID` - javascript works like this ... a variable has one value ... that's it - it can't have a value "that you want" it has the value that it has

Comment: you could pass the the value of the id in `onclick='confirmationBox(id)'` ... and then `function confirmationBox(puzzleID) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop keeps reassigning `puzzleId`. When you call `confirmationBox()`, it will have the last value that was assigned, not the one that was assigned before each `<td>`.

Instead of using a global variable, use a function parameter.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "<td><a href='puzzleedit.php?=" . $row['id'] . "'>Edit</a> | <button onclick='confirmationBox(" . $row['id'] . ")'>Delete</button></td>";
}
```

```
function confirmationBox(puzzleID) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this puzzle?")) {
        window.location = './puzzledelete.php?=' + puzzleID
    } else {
    }
}
```